# Unable to return user from service model

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I need to return user from my service model to controller model but i am not able to do that can anybody help me that ?

```
async function create(userParam) {


if (await User.findOne({ username: userParam.username })) {
    throw 'Username "' + userParam.username + '" is already taken';
}

const user = new User(userParam);
console.log("User", userParam , user )
// hash password
if (userParam.password) {
    user.hash = bcrypt.hashSync(userParam.password, 10);
}

// return user from here
await user.save();
}
```

Comment: `return await user.save()`

Comment: @Baruch `await` is [not neccessary](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-await), `return user.save()` should be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this `

```
user.save().then(item =>{
 return item ;
}
```

`

Comment: This wouldn't work. You are returning the user to the promise callback, not to the `create` function.